# Can I refere to any other xml to style my dynamic layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

using 'for' loop I am creating some dynmic layouts but I don't want to code them. I want to take reference from any other layout xml file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something along the lines of following:

```
        for (some loop) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.some_layout, null);
            containerView.addView(view);
         }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. This works fine for me. But what if I happen to have a TextView in some_layout and I also want to repeat it along with my for loop. So, my quetion is how will I set text to this TextView which is in some_layout.xml

Comment: @RahulPunase you should be able to do something like `TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);`